# is it possible to do range bar chart with curve line ( S Curve)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-visualization

I attached the graph I want to achieve.. can you recommend any library/ how to do this kind of graph?

I looked at libraries such as charts.js, anycharts,canvasJs, High Charts (has payment client wouldn't like that) One interesting I found is Google Charts' Combo chart but have no idea how to do it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm5uf.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used d3 Line chart and append it on top of the progress bar chart. since it's an svg the background is transparent. hope that helps someone